# Create function GetAllChechedBox with text and value and insert in new DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checklistbox

I want to take the text and value from selected and not selected elements from CheckBoxList and insert in datatable

MultiCheckCombo [Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66572/A-Multiple-Selection-DropDownList-a-CheckBoxList-I)

Now I want to get text and value from this checklist, 
    I think it would be comfortable to place in a DataTable

```
public DataTable GetAllChechedBox()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < chkList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (chkList.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Value");
                  // how add all checked with value and text in this datatable?
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

/*also want to take a function with text and value for unselected elements*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of chkList.Items[i].Selected, use chkList.Items[i].Checked....plus
add column outside loop

```
public DataTable GetAllChechedBox()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Value");
            for (int i = 0; i < chkList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (chkList.Items[i].Checked)
                {
                  dt.Rows.Add();
                   dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-1]["Name"] = chkList.Items[i].Value;
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-1]["Value"] = chkList.Items[i].Text;

                }
            }
        return dt;
    }
```